# Sort collection by object attribute

Tags: android, collections

I have an `ArrayList` which consists in a collection of a complex object.
This object has a date field.
I want to sort my list from this date on.

In example

```
class Student{
 int ID;
 Date joinDate;

}

ArrayList <Student> students;
```

How can I sort this students collection from `joinDate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement Comparable interface in Student class

Then you have to override following method in your Student class

```
public int compareTo(Reminder o) {
        return getJoinDate().compareTo(o.getJoinDate());
}
```

Then you use in-built sort method of collections class to sort your objects by date

```
Collections.sort(students);
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement Comparable and the method compareTo

```
public class Student implements Comparable<Student>{

    public int compareTo(Student otherStudent){
       // compare the two students here
    }

}

Collections.sort(studentsArrayList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a `Comparator` and pass it to the sort function. It's a lot better than changing your data class just to provide one kind of ordering.

```
Collections.sort(students, new Comparator<Student>() {
   public int compare(Student e1, Student e2) {
       return e1.joinDate.compareTo(e2.joinDate);
   }
});
```

Or in java 8:

```
Collections.sort(students, (e1, e2) -> e1.joinDate.compareTo(e2.joinDate));
```

For more information check this [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html).